# MATE Indicator Applet 1.24 - How do I change spacing of icons?

Tags: 20.04, indicator, mate

Does anyone know how I can modify the spacing between the icons on MATE indicator applet (1.24)?
It's spaced a little too far apart for my liking and wish to reduce it.

Running on Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible by using CSS file:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/gtk-3.0/
cat << EOF >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

#fast-user-switch-applet * {
 padding: 0 1px 0 1px;
}
EOF
```

It will change the default

> [image: default]

to

> [image: new]

You can adjust the values to which you like.

Comment: Thanks N0rbert, worked a treat :-)

Answer (score 1):

Edit the `gtk.css` configuration file:

```bsh
$ nano ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

Add the following towards the end:

```css
#fast-user-switch-applet * {
   /* for MATE */
   padding-left:  0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Test with:

```bsh
$ mate-panel --replace &
```

In contrast to other answers, **the vertical spacing of pull-up menus** on the indicator applet will remain unchanged.

[image: MATE Indicator-Applet spacing]

Comment: As noted in the answer, the padding also affects the indicator applet pull-up menus.  The left and right paddings of 0px caused me issues with the menus (menu items were cut off or overlapping with each other).  I found setting these paddings to 3px is the sweet spot - the icon spacing is good and the menus work well.  YMMV

Comment: FWIW, based on my testing the default for left and right padding seems to be 8px

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment below the above answer to say thanks (so THANKS!), but I wanted to share what I did for those who may want to have the indicator even more compact. Obviously I'm just replacing the **1px** to **0px**, but since there was a marked difference in doing that, I thought I'd share a comparison pic showing default spacing, 1px and 0px.

[image: Default Spacing, 1 Pixel, and Zero Spacing]

As you can see, while setting the spacing to 1px frees up the space of maybe 1.5 indicators, setting it to 0px frees up the space of at least 3, which means more space for your panel launchers. I personally prefer that, but if it appears too cramped for you, then stick with 1px.

Since most will already have the **gtk-3.0** folder, and probably the **gtk.css** file:

```
gedit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

And add to the end:

```
#fast-user-switch-applet * {
 padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
}
EOF
```

Save the file, then run:

```
mate-panel --replace
```

... if running via Alt+F2, or if via terminal:

```
mate-panel --replace &
```

Hope that helps someone. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This are the proper CSS rules for a GTK theme (they don't mess up the menus) -- replace `2px` with a value of your liking:

```css
.mate-panel-menu-bar.horizontal #fast-user-switch-menubar > menuitem {
  padding: 0 2px;
}
.mate-panel-menu-bar.vertical #fast-user-switch-menubar > menuitem {
  padding: 2px 0;
}
```

I found this by running `GTK_DEBUG=interactive mate-panel --replace`, then `GTK_DEBUG=interactive /usr/lib/mate-indicator-applet-complete` in another shell, then `killall mate-indicator-applet-complete` and reloading the applet. This opens a debugging window for the applet area.

Then go to Objects, switch to CSS nodes in the top left corner and navigate the tree to find the `menuitem`-s.
Then, in the right corner, scroll to the `padding-left` CSS property and there you should see the line in the `gtk.css` file in your theme which handles the styling of those elements.